# meu codigo nao funciona python

Tags: python

```
for i in x:
    print("Jogador 1, selecione a linha para ataque: ")
    LinhaAtaque1 = int(input("Linha do ataque: "))
    print ("Jogador 1, selecione a coluna para ataque: ")
    ColunaAtaque1 = int(input("Coluna do ataque: ")

    if board2[LinhaAtaque1][ColunaAtaque1] != "0":
        print("Você atingiu um navio!!!!!!!!")
        from random import randint
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código que você enviou está sem formatação adequada... Formatando aqui, notei um erro de sintaxe no trecho `ColunaAtaque1 = int(input("Coluna do ataque: ")`.
Está faltando um ')' ao final do comando.